# Not repeating elements in repeated random choice

Tags: python, python-3.x

I have two text files, `students` and `questions`. In `students` are students and in `questions` are questions. Each student corresponds to one question, but sometimes questions are the same and I want to not repeat questions.

```
import random

k = int(input("how many questions do you want ? -"))
questions1 = open("question.txt",'r')
studenti = open("students.txt",'r')
splited = questions1.read().split('\n')
splitedstud = student1.read().split('\n')

for studens in splitedstud:
    file = open(studens + ".txt", "w")
    for i in range(int(k)):
         questiion = random.choice(splited)
         file.write(questiion + '\n')
         file1 = open(studens + ".txt", "r")
         f = file1.read()
         if questiion in f:
             continue
    file.close()

questions.close()
students.close()
```

Comment: splited = list(set(questions1.read().split('\n')))?

Comment: it's work bro, this code works, i want to add not repeating questions.

Comment: Variable names which are typos of real words are a nuistance.

Comment: And many more languages in [Wiktionary](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/studenti) but there is no entry for `splited` either, and I somehow doubt [studens](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/studens) is the intended meaning.

Comment: Ok, ok I cave. He should use a spell checker - as should I :)

Comment: @tripleee I guess there are various ways to deal with the variable-naming problem. At least for me, I have no ground to comment on the _style_ of others, in my code they would probably be called `qs`, `std`, `splt` and similar mutilations. :P

Comment: I actually posted that comment as a joke (notice the typo) and I agree that this is just a matter of style; but there is some seriousness here. I remember reading in [a book](https://www.amazon.com/Enough-Rope-Shoot-Yourself-Foot/dp/0070296898) a suggestion to use a spelling checker on your code just to avoid silly misspellings, and of course then to make sure your variables are actually spelled correctly.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to pair up each student with exactly one question use:

```
import random

studs = [chr(ord('a')+x) for x in range(20)]   # testdata - instead of your read in files
ques = ["question"+str(x) for x in range(20)]  # the files in, just demodata

random.shuffle(ques) # get questions into a random arrangement

for p in  zip(studs,ques):  # pairs each student to the same indexed question [(s1,q1),...]
    with open(p[0]+".txt","w") as f:  # with syntax: better than using blank open/close ops
        f.write(p[1])
```

Output:

```
20 files 'a.txt' to 'p.txt' containing one random question from ques - no duplicates over all files.
```

If either list given as input to [`zip()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#zip) is shorter, zip will only create pairs up to that item, the rest is discarded - so make sure you have at least `len(studenti)` questions.

---

For more then one question per student without repeat you can  use:

```
for s in studs:
    # randomize questions for each student
    random.shuffle(ques)   
    amount = random.randint(3,8)  # how many to be put into file
    with open(s+".txt","w") as f:
        for n in (range(amount)): # write questions into file
            f.write(ques[n] + "\n")
```

Output:

```
20 files 'a.txt' to 'p.txt' containing random 3-8 question from ques - no duplicates inside each file.
```

**Remark:**

this is much slower then [the solution by Jojo](https://stackoverflow.com/a/48187707/7505395) using `random.sample(..)` because you need to reshuffle the compllete list of question for each student, while `random.sample()` will only draw k samples per student.

Doku for shuffle: https://docs.python.org/3/library/random.html#random.shuffle

Comment: @Irakli my solution performs _WORSE_ then  [jojos answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/48187707/7505395) - I would choose his over mine - just saying.

Answer (score 1):

**What you want is to draw a [random sample](https://docs.python.org/2/library/random.html#random.sample) of the questions**. From the docs:

> *random.sample(population, k)*: Return a k length list of unique elements chosen from the population sequence. Used for random sampling without replacement.

In that way you avoid drawing the same question multiple times for a single student.

Something like:

```
for studens in splitedstud:
    file = open(studens + ".txt", "w")
    random_questions = random.sample(splited, k)
    for rand_question in random_questions:
         file.write(rand_question + '\n')
    file.close()
```

Comment: I don't think this is what the OP is having a problem with. They want unique samples from a set which contains duplicates.

Comment: @tripleee note that even if the set does not contain duplicates, you still could get duplicates if you do just a `random.choice`.

Comment: @tripleee also it seems, that this was what the OP was having problems with.

Comment: @tripleee the code he provided in the question produces the same question for studens "by chance" even if he has unique questions in the file. I interpreted the same and provided a solution to uniquely assing each question only once by shuffling/zipping insteadof sampling. Then saw that he wants mutliple q per student so have to alter mine.

Answer (score 0):

Change

```
splited = questions1.read().split('\n')
```

to

```
splited = list(set(questions1.read().split('\n')))
```

to remove all duplicate questions.

Comment: when i try to change, error:
 file.write(kitxvaa + '\n')
TypeError: can only concatenate list (not "str") to list

Comment: Thats a nice short way to write it. But I think it's a bit slower than my way.
I quess choice depends on the amount of all questions. But I don't think that the amount of questions is that large that it would make a difference.

Comment: @Irakli Can you provide more info on the error? where is 'file.write(kitxvaa + '\n')' in your code

Comment: If `splited` was a list before and it's also a list after this change then the error is unrelated to this change.